# Как разделить рандомные элементы в массиве

Tags: xcode, swift

Чтобы потом разделить по  методу split и потом вывести каждое слово в отдельности

```
var text = ["food - еда", "read - читать", "tea - чай"]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(text.count)))
let separeteArr = text[randomIndex].characters.split{$0 == " - "}.map(String.init)

separeteArr[0]  // food (для примера)
separeteArr[1]  // еда (для примера)

// выводится  error: missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен в правильности. Нет пк под рукой, что бы проверить, но вы не верно устанавливаете предел.

Поясню. `arc4random_uniform(5)` - генерирует случайное число в диапазоне от **0 до 5**. Т.е. у вас массив имеет три элемента и вы получаете `arc4random_uniform(3)`, число в диапазоне от **0 до 3**. Но индексы элементов вашего массива 0,1,2 - **у вас просто нет элемента с индексом 3**.

Попробуйте так - `let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(text.count - 1)))`

Comment: Не не так, 
   
     let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(text.count))) 

Он нужен для того чтобы вывести значение из массива, чтобы получилось рандомное значение, к примеру (food - еда)

А  эта строка:

let separeteArr = text[randomIndex].characters.split{$0 == " - "}.map(String.init) 

Она должна разделить по " - " полученный из  randomIndex 1 элемент.

Comment: Вы прочли мой комментарий? Я пояснил почему вы получаете не верный индекс.

Comment: А все дошло спасибо!

Comment: Лучшая благодарность, это ответить вопрос как решение)